# If a div is not dialog then make it dialog otherwise don't

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div:

```
<div id="dialog">Dialog content here</div>
```

I have a function:

```
function process() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen:false});
}
```

I make the dialog only if it is not already created. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `data`. If the dialog is created on the element, then it has 'dialog' as a property of the `data`:

```
function process()
{
    if( !$('#dialog').data('dialog') ){
        $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen:false});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `$("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen:false});` into your `document.ready()` event. Finally, in your `process()` function, add

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
```